# Is it possible to detect the finish of all asynchronous tasks on a web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

it's all in the title. I need to know when all asynchronous tasks are finished on my web page. Is it possible with a kind of custom listener or something?

Comment: You can't detect such event from code embedded in webpage.

Comment: You don't say if you are the initiator of all of these events. If you have control over the creation of these asynchronous events then you can use promises.

Comment: Did you start all the ajax calls?

Comment: i'm not the creator of the tasks they belongs to an ASP.NET application and i need to execute something depending on their fail or success

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't exist a reliable and standard way to detect the finish of all asyncronous tasks. If you're using javascript in your webpage then the scripts can run new asynchronous requests at any time, based on their functionality.

If you're using jQuery and all requests are initiated by you, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
var ajaxfinished = 0;
var totalAjax = 5; //Total of ajax functions you have

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() { //Listener for a complete Ajax function
  ajaxFinished += 1;
  if (ajaxFinished == totalAjax) { //here you know that all tasks are finish
      //run your code
  }
});
```

Take a look here to [.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/), the major con of do that if that you will be very careful with totalAjax.